# External fingerprint integration with android device

Tags: android, sdk, fingerprint

I'm developing an APP for android devices and I'm needing to authenticate the employees with their fingerprint. I have some questions to help me develop it in the best way.

1. Is there an android device with integrated fingerprint scanner and you can retrieve the info of the image template?
2. Is there an external scanner which can be used as an external hardware on my app, USB or Bluetooth?
3. Do the devices offer a android SDK, or an API for integration with my App.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is there an android device with integrated fingerprint scanner and you can retrieve the info of the image template?

   - https://www.morpho.com/en/biometric-terminals/mobile-terminals/morphotablet-2
   - https://www.famoco.com/android-devices/biometric-devices/
2. Is there an external scanner which can be used as an external hardware on my app, USB or Bluetooth?
3. Do the devices offer a android SDK, or an API for integration with my App.

   - https://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?group=platforms_linux_android (SDK supporting multiple fingerprint readers)
   - https://medium.com/touch4it/fingerprint-external-scanner-with-usb-database-sdk-64c3ec5ea82d (tuto)
   - https://www.crossmatch.com/biometric-identity-solutions/products/hardware/single-finger-readers/ (USB fingerprint readers)
   - https://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs88h.html (USB fingerprint reader)
   - https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/fips-fingerprint.html (need to get SDK with device)

Comment: The answer of the third question is not helping a lot. didn't find any SDK for android.